# Who is the person behind Ethereum?

Tags: history

Is Vitalik Buterin a real person or a pseudonymous name like Satoshi Nakamoto? I see videos and pictures of him.  But is he really the person behind Ethereum?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no Vitalik Buterin. Vitalik Buterin is a lie, invented by the Soviet shadow government to distract attention from the upcoming conspiracy to institute the new world order with the People's Bank of China and R3. These are not the Vitalik Buterin you are looking for.

Answer (score 10):

He's a real person https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitalik_Buterin

Vitalik wrote the [Ethereum Whitepaper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper), which could be described as "starting" Ethereum.  He has implemented many things in Ethereum, and it would be safe to say if a single face had to be put on Ethereum, it would be his.  That said launching Ethereum was a sizable team effort and one can look at the [Ethereum Github](https://github.com/ethereum) to see different contributors from across Ethereum's broad stack (such as C++, Go, Java, Javascript, Python).